# java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error java.io.IOException on connect to database

Tags: java, jdbc, informix, tomcat8

I am having a random problem that when performing the connection with informix the following error occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error java.io.IOException
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.handleSocketException(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(Unknown `enter code here`Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executePrepare(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.setupExecutePrepare(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.processSQL(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.createPreparedStmt(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:291)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:291)
at br.com.solcast.integrador.dao.sisdia.PedidoVendaDAO.carregar(PedidoVendaDAO.java:169)
at br.com.solcast.integrador.service.sisdia.PedidoVendaService.carregar(PedidoVendaService.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at br.com.solcast.integrador.security.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.java:43)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at com.informix.asf.IfxDataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at com.informix.asf.IfxDataInputStream.readSmallInt(Unknown Source)
... 61 more
```

My class that connects

```
public class DAOManager {
    private DataSource src;
    private Connection con;

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        try {
            if(this.con==null || this.con.isClosed())
                this.con = src.getConnection();
        } catch(SQLException e) { throw e; }
    }

    public void close() throws SQLException {
        try { 
            if(this.con!=null && !this.con.isClosed()) {
                this.con.close();
                this.con    = null;
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) { 
            throw e; 
        } finally {
            if (this.con != null) {
                try { this.con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                this.con = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public DAOManager() throws NamingException {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();            
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        this.src            = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/cortex-sisdia");
    }

    public Object gerarDAO(DAO dao) throws SQLException 
    {
        if (this.con == null || this.con.isClosed())   
            this.open();

        switch (dao) {
        case AGENDAMENTOOFICINA:
            return new AgendamentoOficinaDAO(this.con);

        case ESTOQUE:
            return new EstoqueDAO(this.con);

        case PEDIDOVENDA:
            return new PedidoVendaDAO(this.con);

        case PESSOA:
            return new PessoaDAO(this.con);

        case VEICULO:
            return new AgendamentoOficinaDAO(this.con);

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize()
    {
        try{
            this.close(); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{ 
            try {
                super.finalize();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

After instantiating a new connection and executing a prepareStatement the error occurs randomly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. It is going to be hard to help much without more information, but I recognize that it may be hard to get more information. And I'm not referring to the extra 61 levels of traceback information! On the face of it, there is a problem with the socket that Informix is using (based on `com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.handleSocketException`). The random misbehaviour is irksome (for everyone). I'm not sure how Java code can write out of bounds, but its the sort of thing that might be an explanation if it was a C client (but it isn't).

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem with a smaller stack, then you should consider contacting IBM/Informix Technical Support.  If the full implementation is needed, it may be harder.  You'll probably be familiar with the concepts of MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — they help with problem/bug reporting in all technical contexts.  You've not said how common the problem is — just that it's random (so not fully consistent).

Comment: The problem sounds either networking related (broken connections), or incorrect protocol behavior. You might want to contact Informix support for more help, maybe your driver is too old (or too new) for the Informix version you are using, etc.